# How can I set the width of `lrbox` in latex?

Tags: boxes, box

I need to set the width of `lrbox` to a particular size. I am trying with the following code:

```
\begin{lrbox}[width=.5\linewidth]
  ...
\end{lrbox}
```

However, it is throwing error. Any idea how can I set the width of lrbox? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome! You can use e.g. `\makebox` or `\parbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newsavebox\mybox
\begin{document}
\begin{lrbox}\mybox
\makebox[.5\linewidth][l]{pft}
\end{lrbox}

\usebox\mybox
\medskip

The width of the \texttt{lrbox} is \texttt{\the\wd\mybox}, and the line width is
\texttt{\the\linewidth}.
\bigskip

\begin{lrbox}\mybox
\parbox{.5\linewidth}{pft pft pft pft pft pft pft pft pft pft pft pft pft pft pft pft pft pft pft pft pft pft}
\end{lrbox}

\usebox\mybox
\medskip

The width of the \texttt{lrbox} is \texttt{\the\wd\mybox}, and the line width is
\texttt{\the\linewidth}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Further options include using a `minipage`.

Comment: +1 i wondered if it might be possible to do it with a list environment, which might allow page breaks...?

Comment: @cmhughes For that one can use a breakable `tcolorbox`. But of course this will no longer be an `lrbox`/`savebox`, which to the best of my knowledge do not support page breaks.